# Is regex available in Sigil clip editor?

Tags: epub, sigil

[image: Clip Editor in Sigil]
I see that the Sigil Clip Editor has some basic regex (e.g., the first numbered group `\1` matches the entire selected text in the replace text and `\U` recalls the text with the entire selected text in uppercase), but I don't see any specification of the syntax for the Clip Editor. Does anyone know what the full range of regex available to the Clip Editor?
Specifically, I am wondering if I can easily parse the selected text using regex pattern and replace it with some other text using the Clips functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Sigil Clip Editor cannot use replace patterns. The way that Sigil Clips works is you highlight text, and then you apply the Clip.

Your highlighted text will be grouped into:

```
\1
```

So let's say you highlight:

`This is text I |want in italics|.`

Clip: `<i>\1</i>`

`This is text I <i>want in italics</i>.`

Clips are designed more as a one-button-push for redundant stuff (like pasting in template code for a figure with caption, etc. etc.)

For example, mobileread user Tex2002ans created this Sigil Clip for himself:

```
<div class="chart">
      <div class="single-chart">
        <div class="chart-title"></div>

        <div class="image"></div>

        <div class="chart-caption"></div>
      </div>
</div>
```

and then he can easily just insert the needed info/images.

To do more advanced Search/Replace using Regex, you use **Tools > Saved Searches**.
https://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?p=3808345#post3808345